# App like Trello for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there an app like Trello for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? OFFLINE mode is preferred.

I need it to organise my things, like this

[image]

Comment: I know [Trello](https://trello.com/home) but you need to tell us what features you need, and preferably the use-case, to make this question answerable and useful to others

Comment: @Zanna The feature that I need the most is: Make my things organized.

Comment: that's not a feature, but I guess it's a use-case in the broadest possible terms. by feature I mean, cards (which can contain x y z), lists (to put the cards in eg todo, done), labels (highly customizable) etc etc

Comment: @Zanna oh, sorry, as of now I just need to organize my things, like this in Trello's website, http://imgur.com/a/p4hvm.